# How to implement SET_DATE_PART in SQL SERVER

Tags: sql-server, informatica

I want to implement SET_DATE_PART function of Informatica which sets part of a date column to particular value in SQL Server. I have a expression upon which I am trying to implement any function similar to `SET_DATE_PART` function of Informatica. This expression

```sql
case 
when ISDATE(SUBSTRING(COLUMN,1,7))=1 and CAST(SUBSTRING(COLUMN,1,2) AS INTEGER)<=7 then 
DATEADD(MM,-1,CONVERT(DATE,SUBSTRING(COLUMN,1,7),106)) 
ELSE CONVERT(DATE,SUBSTRING(COLUMN,1,7),106)
END AS TRANSFORMED  FROM TABLE
ORDER BY 1
```

is working fine for me and returning date values in `YYYY-MM-DD` format. Now I want to set value coming in Date part of my expression to 01. I have tried lots of functions of SQL server like DATEPART,DATEADDbut nothing is working

Comment: FYI, `ISDATE` is really not a great function, and it's use if not recommended. It can easily give false positives. I suggest using `TRY_CONVERT`. Also, avoid using the ordinal position in your `ORDER BY`. Define the columns by their name/alias.

Comment: Is `COLUMN` a `varchar` or a `date/datetime`?

Comment: I would start by storing dates as dates instead of strings.

Comment: VARCHAR.but anyway the returning value from case 
when ISDATE(SUBSTRING(COLUMN,1,7))=1 and CAST(SUBSTRING(COLUMN,1,2) AS INTEGER)<=7 then 
DATEADD(MM,-1,CONVERT(DATE,SUBSTRING(COLUMN,1,7),106)) 
ELSE CONVERT(DATE,SUBSTRING(COLUMN,1,7),106)
END AS TRANSFORMED is a date value.And I want to apply anything equivalent to SET_DATE_PART in SQL SERVER

Comment: Anyone can please help?

Answer (score 1):

Simplifying your problem, let's assume that you already have something that has a datatype of `date`. Once you have that, you can get a different date that has the same year and month of the one provided but the day is set to 1 with the following:

```
declare @d date = sysdatetime();
select @d as old, DATEFROMPARTS(
    datepart(year, @d),
    datepart(month, @d),
    1
) as new;
```